# Quick add entry with details in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Some observations first:

When you are in **Month View** in Google Calendar and enter an event name in the pop-up, it will be created as a **whole-day event**.

OTOH, if you enter the event name like "19:15 Foo" or "14-16 bar", then Google Calendar will be smart enough to create the event **with correct time** (and remove the hours from the name itself). Cool - significantly removes the clicks needed to add something.

My question: What more can be done this way? Can I easily add an event with auto-repeat, for example? What else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Quick Add parser](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=36604) is pretty powerful.

- Include a location by using "at" and a non-time value: `Lunch noon tomorrow at Luigi's Pizza`
- Set recurring events: `Conference call 10am every Tuesday for 11 weeks`

Take a look here for more examples: [Google Support: Create an Event](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/72143)