# How can I disable the Quick Add parser in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

As described [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/quick-add-entry-with-details-in-google-calendar), Google Calendar's [Quick Add parser](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/36604?hl=en) does a lot.  That includes a lot that I don't want it to do and I would really much prefer just disabling it altogether and keeping event titles exactly as I enter them.  The [relevant question was closed in the Google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/d7yZYwOIHxw) but is there now any way to disable this?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is enclose the event name in double quotes. This prevents anything inside the quotes from being parsed. The quotes themselves are automatically removed from the event name if the entire name is in quotes.

Comment: This is the only helpful solution I can find on the entire internet.

Comment: This is a pretty good almost-solution, but as of Feb 2021, the quotes force it to skip parsing the text, but they aren't removed. Perhaps they used to strip the quotes but they aren't now.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly there's nothing in the Google Calendar settings to allow you to disable the Quick Add. (Not even Labs.)

At best you could probably use a custom style sheet to hide the field, but that won't turn off the functionality.