# How do I invite others to my Google Calendar event using Quick Add?

Tags: google-calendar

I want to be able to schedule a meeting with someone else at my company in as few steps as possible.

It looks like the Quick Add feature used to auto-invite email addresses that you included in the event text: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26880/127103. This no longer seems to be the case.

Was this removed? Any way to bring it back? Any other ways to quickly schedule with a certain person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that functionality was removed in the latter half of 2013 or early 2014.

Compare these pages from the Wayback Machine:

- [Google Support: About the 'Quick Add' feature - captured 2013-04-04](http://web.archive.org/web/20130405061614/http://support.google.com/calendar/answer/36604)

  Specifically mentions using an email address as part of the string.
- [Google Support: About the 'Quick Add' feature - captured 2014-04-21](http://web.archive.org/web/20140421180628/https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/36604)

  You'll note that where it used to see you just needed to include "What, When, Who, Where", it now just tells you it needs "What, When, Where".

I don't know why it was removed. I suspect because it was too easy for people to get spammed with event invitations they didn't want.

To invite people you need to use the full event editor.